# check for subnet conflicts

Tags: python, networking

I'm writing a script that gets a /16 and breaks it down into different subnets (/24, 23, 27, etc).  I realized that I may run into conflicting subnets, and I'm looking for a way to check that.  I haven't found anything within ipcalc or netaddr that addresses this specifically.  Thank youf or your help

```
def subnetting(self, cidrBlock, subnets):
            networks = subnets
            cidrblock = cidrBlock
            assigned_subnets = []
            ipnetwork = IPNetwork(cidrblock)
            subnet_list = ipnetwork.subnet(int(subnets))
            for subnet in subnet_list:
                    assigned_subnets.append(subnet)
            return assigned_subnets
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare two subnets to see if they conflict, you need to apply the smallest mask to both to see if they are equal. If they are equal, then you have a conflict.

I will assume the `10.10.0.0/16` network. If you create `10.10.0.0/23` and `10.10.1.0/24`, you compare them by applying the mask for `/23` (`255.255.254.0`) to both `10.10.0.0` and `10.10.1.0`.

```
10.10.0.0 AND 255.255.254.0 = 10.10.0.0
10.10.1.0 AND 255.255.254.0 = 10.10.0.0
```

They are equal, so they overlap and conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [ipconflict](https://github.com/fgiuba/ipconflict).

```
ipconflict 10.0.1.0/24 10.0.1.0/22
```

Output:

```
conflict found: 10.0.1.0/24 <-> 10.0.1.0/22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network) module that's available since Python 3.3.

```
import ipaddress

cidr1 = ipaddress.ip_network("10.10.0.0/23")
cidr2 = ipaddress.ip_network("10.10.1.0/24")
print("Conflict?", cidr1.overlaps(cidr2))
```